# How to get value of xml file

Tags: php, xml, sparql

My sparql output in xml like this :

```
<sparql xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#">
<head>
    <variable name="judulNaskah"/>
    <variable name="linkNaskah"/>
</head>
<results ordered="false" distinct="false">
<result>
    <binding name="judulNaskah">
        <literal>
                Perancangan Aplikasi Fuzzy Multi Criteria Decision Making (FMCDM) Untuk Menentukan Nilai Ketidakpastian Sistem Pakar
        </literal>
    </binding>
    <binding name="linkNaskah">
        <literal>
                http://seminar.ilkom.unsri.ac.id/index.php/ars/article/view/343
        </literal>
    </binding>
</result>
<result>
    <binding name="judulNaskah">
        <literal>
                Implementasi Metode Fuzzy Sugeno Pada Robot Kapal Penghindar Rintangan
        </literal>
    </binding>
    <binding name="linkNaskah">
        <literal>
                http://seminar.ilkom.unsri.ac.id/index.php/ars/article/view/80
        </literal>
    </binding>
</result>
</results>
</sparql>
```

I want to get value all of tag literal, I try this code :

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($hasil) or die("Error: Cannot create object");foreach ($xml->results->result->binding as $node) {
            $arr = $node->attributes();   // returns an array 
            print ($node->literal);
            print ("<br>");
        }
```

`
But my output just give result array [0] like this :
Perancangan Aplikasi Fuzzy Multi Criteria Decision Making (FMCDM) Untuk Menentukan Nilai Ketidakpastian Sistem Pakar
http://seminar.ilkom.unsri.ac.id/index.php/ars/article/view/343

How I get value all of array literal?

Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have object array inside array. 
Try this following code bellow

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($hasil) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach ($xml->results->result as $nodes) {
    foreach ($nodes->binding as $node) {
        echo $node->literal.'<br>';
    }
}   

//echo '<pre>'.print_r( $xml->results->result , true).'</pre>';
```

Hope it helps

edited part

```
$xml        = simplexml_load_string($hasil) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$results    = $xml->results->result;

for($i=0; $i<count($results); $i++) {
    echo $i + 1;
    echo ' .';

    foreach ($results[$i]->binding as $key =>$node) { 
        $output=$node->literal;
        $arr=$node->attributes();
        if ($arr=="linkNaskah"){
            echo "<a href=$output>$output</a><br><br>";
            }
            else {
                echo $key.''.$output.'<br>';
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad it helped, anyway this university is near from my house :)

Comment: Is your house in Semarang? I have one question again : If i want to make list numbering for my output result. I try this code : '$xml=simplexml_load_string($hasil) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
   foreach ($xml->results->result as $key=>$nodes) {
   echo $key;
   foreach ($nodes->binding as $node) {
    $output=$node->literal;
    echo $output.'<br>';
    }
   } 'But the output appear "result" not appear number.

Comment: No I'm from solo. What is your expected output. You can share a screenshot in comment

Comment: My expected output :1.Perancangan Aplikasi Fuzzy Multi Criteria Decision Making (FMCDM) Untuk Menentukan Nilai Ketidakpastian Sistem Pakar
http://seminar.ilkom.unsri.ac.id/index.php/ars/article/view/343 2.Implementasi Metode Fuzzy Sugeno Pada Robot Kapal Penghindar Rintangan
http://seminar.ilkom.unsri.ac.id/index.php/ars/article/view/80 Before judulNaskah make number like (numbering list)